# Why "come blundering by", not "come blunderingly by"?

Tags: grammaticality

> They(Hobbits) possessed from the first the art of disappearing swiftly and silently, when large folk whom they do not wish to meet ***come blundering by***; and this art they have developed until to Men it may seem magical.

It seems to me that "come blunderingly by" make more grammatical sense as the adverb blunderingly modifies the verb come.  I don't understand why the author had used the adjective form 'blundering' here.  Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination [come/go + verb + preposition] is not uncommon.

> Mrs Smith went tottering past on her high heels.

> He came galumphing back. (Lewis Carroll)

Answer (score 2):

**come blundering by**

The verb *come* here is a copula and *blundering by* a participle phrase. Here the copula doesn't describe the manner in which the "large folk" come, but rather the act (of coming) itself. A loose semantic parallel might be "The rose smells sweet (not sweetly)"; Or "He ruled supreme (not supremely)."

*The bottom line is that the adjective/participle in such cases doesn't modify the verb so much as it does the noun.*

Comment: Can it be taken as "come by, blundering"?

Comment: @dan I believe they mean the same thing more or less.